# Cannot GET from Express.js PUT route, why?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, crud

Is there any reason you cannot execute a GET request from inside an Express.js router.put()?

I have two routes. The exact same api call works in a router.get() route and hangs in the router.put().

I've confirmed that

This works:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { headers } = req;
  let result;
  try {
    result = await axios({ method:'get', url: '/some-url', headers });
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(new Error('myError');
  }
  res.send({ result });
});
```

This does NOT work:

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { headers } = req;
  let result;
  let finalResult;

  try {
    result = await axios({ method:'get', url: '/some-url', headers });
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(new Error('myError');
  }

  // logic based on the result of the above GET determines what the value of `finalResult`
  finalResult = { some: 'data' };

  res.send({ finalResult });
});
```

Even though `axios({ method:'get', url: '/some-url' })` is the exact same in both routes, it works in one and not the other.

The `router.put()` route always hangs for a long time and eventually Node outputs:
`Error: socket hang up, code: 'ECONNRESET', etc...`

Appreciate any help, I've spent over a day scratching my head over this.

Comment: Does your `put` request handler in Express even get called?  If so, how far into it does it get?  If it's getting stuck on the axios call, can you show us the actual code for that axios call?  Have you tested that specific axios call separately?

Comment: Yes, it reaches that route and is able to make all other axios calls that it needs. Yes, I have tested it separately, as I point out that the call works within the router.get() callback. I cannot share the code for that code as it contains many specifics about company systems, but it is almost identical to what I've shown in my example.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you expect us to be able to do here without seeing the actual code or being able to run something ourselves and debug it.

Comment: @jaimefps shouldn't the signature be `async (req, res)` ... how can you do `res.send` without throwing an exception?

Comment: and BTW, try to learn how to debug code ... fire up VSCode and attach the process when you run it locally, then simply add a breakpoint and hit that endpoint using `PUT` as the verb ...

Comment: yeah, missed the (req, res) as I was writing pseudo code since I can't share the real code. I know exactly where the code fails. Which is why I ask about the `Error: socket hang up` when a GET is attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause of my problem:**

The http Headers had a key of `Content-Length` that prevented GET calls to resolve correctly.

Since these api calls occurred within a router.put() callback, the Headers had a `Content-Length` pointing to the size of the payload "body" that was being PUT to begin with.

**Solution:**

Remove that `Content-Length` field from my Headers when doing GETs inside router.put(), such that the GET has all the other Headers data except for `Content-Length`

Unfortunately, NodeJS just threw that `Error: socket hang up` message that was not very descriptive of the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no such thing in express. Try hitting the GET request from postman or curl and see if response is coming. The root cause could be an invalid get request you're trying to make or that server on which you are making GET request could be down. You can run following to validate

```js
app.put('/',async (req, res) => {
    let response  = await axios.get('https://google.co.in');
    console.log(response.data);
    res.send({"works": "hello"});
});
```

Comment: I've already tried hitting that GET endpoint directly from the the browser and from POSTMAN, and everything works for that GET request. 

It ONLY fails and hangs when attempting it from inside the router.put() callback.

Comment: On what type of api, you're try to make a GET request. Share the details if it's any public api or if its an internal api, see if you have any checks enabled